# AVD manager, unable to locate ADB

Tags: android, android-studio

just started android studio and set up an emulator. when I am in the virtual devices manager i have a nexus 6P api 30.
when I hit the play button (the green triangle) it says "unable to locate adb" in a small pop-up. however the emulator still runs perfectly fine.

my biggest problem is that when I try running my code in the emulator I have to select a device. however my emulator is not listed as any devices as it says "no devices connected".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found `adb` in `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`. Adding that folder to my `$PATH` in my `.zshrc` (ZSH is my system's default shell) and restarting Android Studio seems to have resolved the error message, though Android Studio still told me one last time that it couldn't find ADB, before never telling me again.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: That's probably on macOS, right? I'm on Debian 11 and Android Studio installed them in `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools`

Comment: @HarmteMolder correct; I'm using macOS 11